# How do I leverage ConstructUsing in a mapping with inherited types?

Tags: c#, inheritance, automapper

I have the following class hierarchy that I need to map, but for some reason my `ConstructUsing` implementation is not being called. I need to intercept the construction of an abstract class in the middle of the hierarchy and create appropriate instances based on a property of the original model.

Entity types:

```cs
public abstract class Profile {}

public sealed class ComposedProfile : Profile 
{
    public int Platform {get; set;}
}
```

DTOs:

```cs
public abstract class ProfileDto {}

public abstract class ComposedProfileDto : ProfileDto { }

public sealed class WindowsProfileDto : ComposedProfileDto { }

public sealed class AndroidProfileDto : ComposedProfileDto { }
```

The mappings I'm currently stuck with:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Profile, ProfileDto>()
    .Include<ComposedProfile, ComposedProfileDto>();

Mapper.CreateMap<ComposedProfile, WindowsComposedProfileDto>()...{some complicated mapping};
Mapper.CreateMap<ComposedProfile, AndroidComposedProfileDto>()...{another complicated mapping}
Mapper.CreateMap<ComposedProfile, ComposedProfileDto>()
    .ConstructUsing(
        source =>
        {
            switch (source.Platform)
            {
                case 0:
                    return Mapper.Map<AndroidComposedProfileDto>(source);

                case 1:
                    return Mapper.Map<WindowsComposedProfileDto>(source);

                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        });
```

I then have the mapping code like this, for example:

```cs
Profile profile = new ComposedProfile();
var mapped = Mapper.Map<ProfileDto>(profile);
```

With the current implementation, the `ConstructUsing` block is never called, and the mapper always tries to map instances of `ComposedProfile` to `WindowsComposedProfile`. This seems to be related to the order of the `CreateMap` calls: if I switch the two specific mapping calls and place the `CreateMap<ComposedProfile, AndroidComposedProfileDto>()` above of the `CreateMap<ComposedProfile, WindowsComposedProfileDto>()`, it then starts mapping to `AndroidComposedProfileDto` all the time.

If I remove both `CreateMap` calls althogether, it then hits my custom `ConstructUsing` block, but of course then fails because I'm using `Map` inside of the method and the maps themselves are not declared.

I need to have both of the features here. I want to have the mappings configured, and I want to also have the custom construction code called. How can I achieve that? As you noticed, I tried many things to no avail. I also tried including the specific mappings with the `Include` call in the original mapping, reordering the `CreateMap` calls, and nothing works.

I have many other classes deriving from `Profile` and `ProfileDto`, but the mapping to the composed dto is the only one giving me problems since I need the custom creation logic (all other mappings are one to one standard mappings). Please keep in mind that my code relies on the mapping to the base dto class, so I can't map to a more specific type at that point. A solution to this problem needs to work with a map to the more basic class.